# Dini's theorem; relaxing the condition of compactness

Tags: real-analysis, functions, compactness, uniform-convergence

Here's Dini's theorem:
If monotone sequence of continuous functions converges pointwise on a compact set $X$ and the limit function is also continuous, then the convergence is uniform.

I wonder if the compactness condition in Dini's theorem can be replaced by its dense set.
For example, suppose that there is a set $Y$ dense in a compact set $X$.
Can we replace $X$ by $Y$ in Dini's theorem?

Comment: To get your conclusion, there is a stronger hypothesis.  Not only each of the functions $f_n$ be continuous, but the whole family $\{f_n\}$ be equicontinuous.

Comment: @GEdgar is there any reference or link about the result with the equicontinuous family of functions?

Comment: It's a step in the proof of the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), which should be discussed in most graduate-level real analysis texts (and some undergraduate ones too).

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. Probably $X$ and $Y$ in my question play a role in the compact set $I$ and the sequence of rational numbers, respectively, in the theorem you suggested, right? Well, as a beginner of real analysis, I need to take a look at the proof of the theorem :)

Comment: Oh, I realised that the additional condition of (uniform) equicontinuity and pointwise convergence on a precompact set imply uniform convergence on the corresponding compact set, which is Arzela-Ascoli theorem. I expected a similar statement of Dini's theorem (with monotonicity) but we can already apply Arzela-Ascoli theorem with equicontinuity.

Answer (score 4):

$Y=[0,1)$ is dense in the compact set $X=[0,1]$, and the sequence of continuous functions $f_n(x) = x^n$ converges monotonically and pointwise on $Y$ to the continuous function 0, but not uniformly.